# Could somebody recognize the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Could somebody recognize the keyboard that the man on [this video](https://youtu.be/Yvco_DWMV_g?t=8m35s) uses?
It has a layout of standard Apple keyboard, but with colored buttons and many extra symbols. Never saw that one in my country.

[image: coloured-keyboard]

Comment: Check this http://logickeyboard.com/shop/logickeyboard-avid-protools-apple-keyboards-979c1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Logickey](http://logickeyboard.com/shop/logickeyboard-avid-protools-apple-keyboards-979c1.html) for an assortment of keyboards and skins for Final Cut / Avid / etc.